# Do Lévy α-stable distributions maximize entropy subject to a simple constraint?

Tags: maximum-entropy, stable-distribution

Is there a simple constraint on real-valued distributions such that the maximum entropy distribution is Lévy α-stable? Special cases include the Normal and Cauchy distributions for which the answer is affirmative; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_entropy_probability_distribution#Examples

Answer (score 0):

I'll go ahead and conjecture a partial answer, simply generalizing the Normal and Cauchy special cases. Let $f(\alpha) = \mathbb E\left[\left(1+X^2\right)^{\alpha-2}\right]$, and consider $f$'s indefinite integral
$$
F(\alpha) = \begin{cases}
  \mathbb E\left[\frac{\left(1+X^2\right)^{\alpha-1}}{\alpha-1} \right] & \alpha \ne 1\\
  \mathbb E\left[\ln\left(1+X^2 \right)\right] & \alpha =1
\end{cases}
$$
**Conjecture:** For any $\alpha\in(0,2]$ and upper bound $U$, the maximum entropy distribution satisfying $F(\alpha) \le U$ is a symmetric Lévy $\alpha$-stable distribution centered at zero and with stability parameter $\alpha$.